# How to sort Django form fields automatically

Tags: python, django

I have a Django ModelForm like this:

```py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def make_this_fields_first(self, my_fields):
          # what can I do here?

    class Meta:
        model= MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

In my view I want to do this:

```py
my_form_obj = MyForm()
my_form_obj.make_this_fields_first(['field6','field3'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `BaseForm`'s [`order_fields()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d1791539a7d86739cd44c909fa8239cae7f85874/django/forms/forms.py#L109) method:

```py
my_form_obj = MyForm()
my_form_obj.order_fields(['field6', 'field3'])
```

Alternatively the `Meta.fields` in a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) are ordered. The form fields will be generated in the same order that they are defined there:

```py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model= MyModel
        fields = ['field6', 'field3', ...]
```